# what is the difference between != and <> operators in php and which is best?

Tags: php, operators

Among != and <> operators, Which is the best operator to use in both arithmetic and string operations. If both are doing same operations, why we need these two operators?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [phpdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) there's no difference.

> $a != $b  **TRUE** if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.'
>
> $a <> $b  **TRUE** if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.

There are two operators for the same job probably because to accommodate programmers' preference.

Comment: Never seen anyone use `<>`, in my opinion `!=` makes more sense

Comment: In sql we use <> normally. In php, yes we dont find often

Answer (score 0):

Both operators are identical. According to the documentation, both return:

> **TRUE** if `$a` is not equal to `$b` after type juggling.

Why do we need both? For no real reason. Probably in order to make PHP easy to adapt to for as many programmers as possible - including those who have different habits with regard to the inequality check operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference together

you can also see this page : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp